# QListWidgetItem items overlap each other

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qlabel, qlistwidgetitem

I have defined a widget, which contains a QLabel (and other elements) that should show wrapped text.
This QLabel has:
Horizontal Policy: Minimum
Vertical Policy: MinimumExpanding
WordWrap:  true

The widget has:
LayoutSizeConstraint: SetMinimumSize

Other than that a I have another widget which contains QListWidget item.
I want to add the widget with QLabel as many times as I want. To do that I use a helper:

```
QListWidgetItem* showWidgetOnTheList(QListWidget* view, QWidget* widget)
{
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(view);
    QSize size(view->size().width(), widget->height());
    item->setSizeHint(size);
    view->addItem(item);
    view->setItemWidget(item,widget);
    return item;
}
```

The final result is that I see elements which overlap each other. What is the proper solution?

Comment: The cause of the problem is QLabel which does not return proper size (when wordWrap flag is on) as long as it is not shown. There is a workaround: I can call on layout, that this QLabel belongs to, two methods: invalidate() and activate().

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `setMinimumSize()` for a `QLabel`, and `QLabel` has parent.
use a `QGridLayout` as parent of your widget. layout apply minimum size of it's children.

if you don't want to use `QGridLayout`, you can `setMinimumSize()` for parent to proper value.
this value is sum  of minimum size of all it's children.